# SQL Where at least all specified

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns a list of threads. Each thread can have multiple posts attached to them, and each post can have multiple tags attached.

Consider the following data,

```
INSERT INTO thread(id, title) VALUES (1, 'Thread A');
INSERT INTO thread(id, title) VALUES (2, 'Thread B');
INSERT INTO thread(id, title) VALUES (3, 'Thread C');

INSERT INTO post(id, body, thread_id) VALUES(1, 'This is some example text', 1);
INSERT INTO post(id, body, thread_id) VALUES(2, 'This is some example text', 1);
INSERT INTO post(id, body, thread_id) VALUES(3, 'This is some example text', 2);
INSERT INTO post(id, body, thread_id) VALUES(4, 'This is some example text', 3);

INSERT INTO tag(id, name) VALUES(1, 'Funny');
INSERT INTO tag(id, name) VALUES(2, 'Boring');
INSERT INTO tag(id, name) VALUES(3, 'Interesting');
INSERT INTO tag(id, name) VALUES(4, 'Weird');

INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (2, 3, 2);
INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (3, 1, 3);
INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (4, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (5, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO tag_post_map(id, tag_id, post_id) VALUES (6, 1, 4);
```

I want to get all threads that have posts with the tags "Funny" and "Interesting" grouping the tags by post, however I do not wish to exclude posts that have more tags, as long as they have those two. That means, I wish to query for AT LEAST the tags that I need for any given thread. "Thread C" should not show up, because it only has a post with the "Funny" and "Boring" tags, not also the required "Interesting" tag.

This is my query currently

```
SELECT thread.id, thread.title from thread where exists (
  select *
  from tag_post_map
  inner join post on post.id = tag_post_map.post_id
  where
    tag_post_map.tag_id in (1, 3)
    and post.thread_id = thread.id
);
```

This also returns "Thread C", which is expected but not what I want. I am not able to figure out how to achieve the desired result.

[And here's an SQL fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8261d/8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to get all threads that have posts with the tags "Funny" and "Interesting" grouping the tags by post,

You can approach this using aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select p.thread_id
from posts p join
     tag_post_map tpm
     on tpm.post_id = p.id join
     tags t
     on tpm.tag_id = t.id
where tpm.name in ('Funny', 'Interesting')
group by p.thread_id
having count(distinct tpm.name) = 2;
```

Note:  The `threads` table is not needed.  In addition, the tags could be on *different* posts for the thread, which appears to be your intention.  Because multiple posts can have the same tag, you cannot use `count(*)`.

Comment: I want to clarify that I do need the threads table, because I intend to join other things onto it. This is purely for filtering.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen . . . This returns the `thread_id`.  You can, of course, include the `threads` table and other columns if your needs are broader than what you describe in the question.

Comment: The problem with this is the group by clause, in my actual code I have a lot of other things being joined and selected to on the "thread" table, which doesn't work with the group by. Ideally, a subquery that I can plop into a WHERE EXISTS would be perfect if possible.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question then ask a *new* question.

Comment: I've managed to modify this to fit in a subquery with where in, and it now works perfectly.